# Create/Alter stored procedure without compiling

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to create or alter a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005* that doesn't compile the procedure?

(* - yes, unfortunately, we still need to support 2005 as our minimum standard)

I have a situation where it would be exceedingly useful to be able to create/alter a stored procedure that is syntactically valid but not semantically valid (due to incorrect table/column names)... which I can then alter accordingly within SSMS.

I've just had a thought, and it's a pretty simple solution... comment out the entire contents of the stored procedure when it's being altered/created.

Using <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> will comment out each line individually - which would be better than using `/* */` around the entire thing, as that will fail if there are any instances of `/* */` in the stored procedure already.

I would still be very interested to hear if there is an actual way to tell SSMS to ignore invalid table/view/column names.

Thanks to @marcelo for his answer, and it does appear that using the name of a non-existent table will allow you to create the stored procedure.

However, it does not allow you to create a stored procedure if you use a non-existent *column* in an existing table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are referring to is deferred name resolution and is further explained here [Deferred Name Resolution and Compilation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.90).aspx).

> Deferred name resolution can only be used when you reference
>   nonexistent table objects. All other objects must exist at the time
>   the stored procedure is created. For example, when you reference an
>   existing table in a stored procedure you cannot list nonexistent
>   columns for that table.

Basically, no you are not able to alter the parsers rules for what objects must exist at parse and compile time. I've previously had this issue when deploying SPs which reference linked servers and those linked servers did not have a valid connection. To work around it I updated the linked sever logic to be dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks @Pixelated, not the answer I wanted, but at least it's definitive!  The important part of the page (which you might want to quote it your answer is this: *Deferred name resolution can only be used when you reference nonexistent table objects. All other objects must exist at the time the stored procedure is created. For example, when you reference an existing table in a stored procedure you cannot list nonexistent columns for that table.*

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in sql server 2005 you can create a stored procedure that references a table that does not exist.
I have just done it, see my example below.

```
--set parseonly on

select @@version
--Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (X64) 
--Dec 10 2010 10:38:40 
--Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
--Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)



use dba
go

create procedure mysp
as 
begin

select getdate()
select * from mytablethatdoesnot exist

end
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response @marcelo. Hmmm, yes, it does appear to be possible for tables, but not for non-existant columns in existing tables.  Any ideas?

Comment: @freefaller No, the only way to bypass compile-time checking for columns is to put the code referencing those columns inside dynamic SQL. Not sure I understand the benefit of bypassing these checks when you can't call that stored procedure until the column exists anyway...

Comment: Thanks @Aaron for your input.  It's complex to explain and I'm sure I would be ripped apart if I did explain, but it's for development purposes - where I have multiple databases that share 95% of tables/columns, but I need to transfer sprocs over including the 5%.  Would be a lot easier if I could transfer and then alter, rather than alter then transfer

Comment: @AaronBertrand I run into the problem frequently because of one method we use to "backup" a SP before making code changes.  We add a date stamp to the end of the SP name and then create the old version under a new name.  If the table structure underneath has changed we can't create the "backup" version.

Comment: @Kenneth See, I would rather keep old versions of the stored procedure offline (source control) than cluttering my database. YMMV, obviously. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I would too but our office environment makes that spotty at best (dev group by dev group) so we go on the better safe than sorry theory.

Comment: @Kenneth you could also create the clone *before* you change the underlying table, or keep versioned backups that you could always restore if you need to. Plenty of ways around deferred name resolution issues.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That assumes the table change and the SP change are related.  The table change may have happened months ago.  Not saying that there aren't other or even better ways.  Just that this is one possible reason for the request.  You could also throw all of the "backup" code into a separate DB for the purpose that has no tables.

Comment: @Kenneth Well that wasn't a very controlled table change if it broke an SP with a dependency. It just seems like you're advocating bad practice #A because you're already using bad practice #B. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18320/discussion-between-kenneth-fisher-and-aaron-bertrand).